# touch scrolling without scroll indicator. Possible?

Tags: css, mobile-webkit

I'm worried that the short answer to this question is NO.

But before I accept this fate I'll attempt a last ditch effort.

Usability concerns aside, is there any way I can do a div overflow for webkit mobile where, when scrolling, I do NOT see the scroll indicator?

I'm really hoping to avoid building a custom scroller in plain JS just because apple insisted on forcing the indicator to always be visible.

Any pointers much appreciated. I've looked around a lot but found nothing useful.

Reminder: **I'm not asking about scroll bar customization!!!** I'm asking about the indicator that shows during touchmove.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this code. But this will only work in Chrome and Safari.

`#element::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}`

Comment: sigh. why do people not read a question before answering... -1

Answer (score -1):

Technically you could do this in Chrome and Safari using the following CSS:

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; }
```

However, for all other browsers you'll need Javascript.  The basic algorithm would be as follows:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">Hello, here's lots of text...</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#content {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT (pseudo-code)**

```
When clicking on #content, check for drag
If dragging then measure amount and invert amount
Set that amount to top position of #content
```

Comment: -1 for not reading the question. i'm NOT(!) asking about the scrollbar.

Comment: Well then, there's no way to do what you're talking about.  If you come here to StackOverflow for help, try not to be so rude.  You downvoted two well-meaning people who genuinely tried to help you.  Try addressing the issue next time rather than passive-aggressively flaming the community of eager **volunteers** that write your code for you.

Answer (score -1):

Keeping with my tradition of answering my own question after extended research, the indicator can be hidden only by removing `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:true` CSS attribute.

This, unfortunately, also removes the spiffy scroll-elasticity feature, which is of course whey one would want to use the above CSS.